# How to rewrite email body before sending using python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, email

Wanted to parse raw mail and add some text in body mail before sending it to the recipient. Mail can be of any type with(out) attachment(s) inline etc. How can we achieve this with minimal python code?

I have tried parsing the mail to get the body part. But to reattach each part by iteration is cumbersome. Any way which we can just get the remaining part of the mail and reattach the body and send ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib, ssl
port = 465
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "my@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "your@gmail.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server,port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

For more info refer : https://realpython.com/python-send-email/

This will give you idea how to set your Gmail account such that a 3rd party software (like python) can access it to send emails. This is to be done only for the sender's email.

Comment: i am talking of parsing a raw mail and adding text to body before sending the mail out

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are saying.Could you give a more detailed question on what you exactly wanna do ( with an example if possible )